# Text box key up event in WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, textbox

How to use ICommand in key up event of a text box using MVVM architecture?

Answer (score 0):

You have a readymade helper class to handle [event to command behaviour](http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2009/11/05/mvvm-light-toolkit-v3-alpha-2-eventtocommand-behavior.aspx) in MVVM Light Toolkit.

Comment: Could you please explain and tell me how to get the dll for that toolkit?

Comment: @gowri-ganapathy: check this link for the installation procedure: http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/installing/manually/

Answer (score 0):

You can use InvokeDataCommand trigger from [Expression Blend Samples](http://expressionblend.codeplex.com/):

```
    <TextBox>
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="KeyUp">
                <si:InvokeDataCommand Command="{Binding MyCommand}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

MVVM doesn't forbid you to write code-behind - this is a common misunderstanding. You can listen to the KeyUp event of the TextBox in the code-behind file of the View and delegate the call to the ViewModel object.

How this works is shown in the **ViewModel** sample application of the **[WPF Application Framework (WAF)](http://waf.codeplex.com)**.